# Detecting when a SVG animation has ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a SVG image inside my body tag that is being animated by the following code:

```
     <clipPath id="left-to-right">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="0%" height="100%" >
         <animate attributeName="width" values="0%;100%" dur="5s" fill="freeze"/>
     </rect>
 </clipPath>
```

I'm adding the .svg to the body via an image tag like so:

```
<body>
 <div id="loading-container">
  <img id="silhoutte" src="Images/Silhoutte.svg">
 </div>
 <div id="content"> 
  /* Content in here */ 
 <div>
</body>
```

The svg is serving as a "loading" animation while i preload/cache some high resolution images before displaying the actual content.

My difficulty is in trying to detect the end of the SVG animation in order to reveal the content div. How would i go about detecting the animation if at all possible?

I'm open to suggestions on better ways to implement a web page loading screen using the animated SVG i created.

Thank you!

Comment: You are using SVG's SMIL animation which has been deprecated. Therefore, look at CSS animations instead. Initially they take a bit of practice to assure cross-browser performance, but work nicely for SVG elements.

Comment: @FrancisHemsher Shortly after posting I realized that it was deprecated! I will look into CSS animations to replicate the effect from SMIL. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

The SVG animation element should fire an [`endEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement/endEvent_event) once the animation is finished, so something like this should work:

```
document.querySelector('#left-to-right animate').addEventListener('endEvent', function() {
    console.log('Animation finished');
}, false);
```

Comment: Not if the animation is in an `<img>` element. Events don't fire from there.

Comment: As @RobertLongson pointed out within an <img> tag you can't fire an event. I also learned that SVG SMIL animations are deprecated and I should be using CSS Animations instead. I should be able to get the event fire of the animation in CSS Animations using the function provided by Schlaus. 
Thank you both!

Comment: @JordyMcnab they are only deprecated in Chrome. Firefox has no plans at the moment to remove them and they are still in the SVG 2 specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/animate.html

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh i see, thank you for the update. The solution to the original question then would be to still use CSS Animations in order to detect the end of animation since an event won't fire within an <img> tag?

Comment: You can't detect the end of any kind of animations if you're using an img tag. You'd need to use another tag.